# Semantic issue with unrelated object in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` subclass that implements a message to init the controller with a custom model:

```
- (id)initWithUser:(FacebookFriend *)user;
```

When I use this to init my controller:

```
ProfileViewController *profileViewController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithUser:friend];
```

The compiler complains about sending a message to `NSUserDefaults`' message of the same name:

```
- (id)initWithUser:(NSString *)username;

warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct FacebookFriend *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'initWithUser:' from distinct Objective-C type
```

I don't quite understand why it's notifying me of this as I don't think `UIViewController` inherits from `NSUserDefaults` anywhere. Is there a way to disable this error? Could this cause a problem? Should I just rename my class' initializer to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have an ambiguous selector. Because `alloc` returns the generic (for Objective C) type `id`, the call to `initWithUser:` has become ambiguous, and so it gets confused with the `NSUserDefaults` method `initWithUser:`. The compiler thinks you're trying to use that one.

You can remove the ambiguity by casting:

```
ProfileViewController *profileViewController = [(ProfileViewController*)[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithUser:friend];
```

Comment: But the compiler should be smart enough to figure that out, and it was in my test just now.

Comment: @jtbandes Why? It received a generic type `id` object and the first method it finds is `- (id)initWithUser:(NSString *)username`.

Comment: @jtbandes: Either your test did not use an incompatible type or you're using some very new compiler version that finally fixes it, because this problem has existed in Objective-C for a very long time.

Comment: Adding the cast suppresses the warning. This was reported as a warning by LLVM GCC 4.2. Got something else @jtbandes?

Comment: Casting suppresses the warning, yes. I don't know why I didn't get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried directly casting the result of `-alloc`? Something like this:

```
ProfileViewController *profileViewController = [(ProfileViewController *)[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithUser:friend];
```

Comment: I know it's necessary. That's why I posted it?